# How to switch page numbers to/from Roman numerals

Tags: context, page-numbering

I am trying to have the page numbering of the front matter in lower case Roman and the rest in Arabic numbers. I also don't want the  number on the title page (though it should be counted). According to the documentation I found (ConTeXt reference manual (2011); ConTeXt garden wiki), I should use something along the lines of

```
\setuppagenumbering[state=stop]
% title page
\setuppagenumbering[state=start,conversion=romannumerals]
% rest of front matter, e.g. TOC
\setuppagenumbering[conversion=numbers]
% body
% back matter
```

Well, the suppression of page numbers on the title page works, but I can't seem to switch to Roman numerals.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Page numbering of the front matter in lower case roman**

Use the following setup

```
\definestructureconversionset [frontpart:pagenumber] [] [romannumerals]
```

If you want additional settings to be applied in the front or bodypart, you can use the command `\startsectionblockenvironment`. Just for demonstration, this is how you reset the page number to one in the bodymatter:

```
\startsectionblockenvironment [bodypart]
  \setcounter [userpage] [1]
\stopsectionblockenvironment
```

Don't forget to mark up you content, so ConTeXt knows where the front and bodymatter is:

```
\startfrontmatter
\stopfrontmatter

\startbodymatter
\stopbodymatter
```

**The rest in Arabic numbers**

That is already the default, there's no need to change that.

**Title page**

A title page is created as follows

```
\startstandardmakeup
  Content of the title page
\stopstandardmakeup
```

By default the page is not counted. To change this use the setting `pagestart=start`, here together with other settings to enlarge the font and to centre the content:

```
\setupmakeup
  [standard]
  [pagestate=start,
   style=bigbodyfont,
   align=middle]
```

Putting it all together leads to the following skeleton:

```
\definestructureconversionset [frontpart:pagenumber] [] [romannumerals]

\setupmakeup
  [standard]
  [pagestate=start,
   style=bigbodyfont,
   align=middle]

\starttext

\startstandardmakeup
  Title page
\stopstandardmakeup

\startfrontmatter
  \completecontent
\stopfrontmatter

\startbodymatter
  \startchapter [title=First chapter]
  \stopchapter
  \startchapter [title=Second chapter]
  \stopchapter
\stopbodymatter

\stoptext
```

Answer (score 4):

According to http://www.mail-archive.com/ntg-context@ntg.nl/msg48251.html, it should be `\setupuserpagenumber`, not `\setuppagenumbering`. The following does the job in my case:

```
\setuppagenumbering[state=stop]
% title page
\setuppagenumbering[state=start]
\setupuserpagenumber[numberconversion=romannumerals]
% rest of front matter, e.g. TOC
\setupuserpagenumber[numberconversion=numbers]
% body
% back matter
```

But I couldn't find anything about the `\setupuserpagenumber` command in ConTeXt Garden, or the reference manual, or here on SE TeX.