# Page numbers in Romannumeral in ConTeXt

Tags: context, page-numbering, roman-numerals

I tried to change the page number into Romannumeral with

```
    \setuppagenumbering[conversion=romannumerals]
```

but it did nothing. I had to use a macro to achieve that:

```
    \def\RomanNumeral#1{\uppercase\expandafter{\romannumeral#1}}
    \setuppagnumbering[command=\RomanNumeral]
```

But it is wrong, it seems that ConTeXt inserts some characters just after `\romannumeral`.

The first example is given in Page 88 of the manual.

Comment: The TeX syntax is wrong, you must remove a pair of braces: `\uppercase\expandafter{\romannumeral#1}`

Comment: Related: [How to switch page numbers to/from Roman numerals](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/65194/5245)

Comment: @egreg: I am wrong! I think I should do the exercise 7.8 and 7.9 again.

Comment: "This is admittedly tricky; the `\expandafter` expands
the token after the `{`, not the token after the group." DEK.

Comment: @egreg:Yeah, in fact I like plain TeX and have read the TeXbook from cover to cover, expecting the second pass:). Sometime plain TeX will take a long time, so I have to use ConTeXt now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get roman page numbering in lowercase use

```
\setupuserpagenumber [numberconversion=romannumerals]
```

for upper case replace it with a capital letter:

```
\setupuserpagenumber [numberconversion=Romannumerals]
                                       ^
```

More information and examples on the wiki: [Page Numbering](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Table_of_Contents#Page_Numbering_in_Table_of_Contents)

Comment: Does this produce uppercase Roman numerals?

Comment: I asked because this seemed to be the OP's main question.

Comment: @Marco: Thanks, it works. I think the ConTeXt manual should be updated. It is too old to contain the new `\setupuserpagenumber`.

Comment: Also, if you need a custom conversion macro, declare it via [`\defineconversion`](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/defineconversion) first. Then you can just hook it into any `numberconversion` parameter you wish -- there’s no reason to resort the `command` key for this.